# Problems with std::chrono

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, g++, c++-chrono

I am having trouble compiling with chrono, here is the code:

Time.hh

```
#include        <chrono>

class           Time
{
protected:
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point _start_t;
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point _now;
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point _time;
public:
  Time();
  Time(const Time &other);
  Time          &operator=(const Time &other);
  ~Time();
public:
  void          start();
  double        getDurSec();
  double        getDurMilSec();
private:
  void          setNow();
};
```

Compilation error:

```
g++  -W -Wall -Wextra -I./include -std=c++0x  -c -o src/Time/Time.o src/Time/Time.cpp
In file included from src/Time/Time.cpp:11:0:
./include/Time/Time.hh:21:3: error: ‘steady_clock’ in namespace ‘std::chrono’ does not     name a type
./include/Time/Time.hh:22:3: error: ‘steady_clock’ in namespace ‘std::chrono’ does not name a type
./include/Time/Time.hh:23:3: error: ‘steady_clock’ in namespace ‘std::chrono’ does not name a type
src/Time/Time.cpp: In member function ‘void Time::start()’:
src/Time/Time.cpp:34:2: error: ‘_time’ was not declared in this scope
src/Time/Time.cpp:34:23: error: ‘std::chrono::steady_clock’ has not been declared
```

Etc...

Tell me if you need more informations.

Comment: It probably won't help but you should not use lead underscore when naming your variables (`_start_t`, `_now`...)

Comment: @jules [They aren't in a global namespace, so they are ok.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1171191)

Comment: What version of g++ are you using, on which operating system?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are probably using a g++ version prior to 4.7.0 where `std::chrono::steady_clock` was not implemented. If this is the case, you have two solutions:

- Upgrade your g++ to 4.7.0 or a more recent version.
- Use instead the old `std::chrono::monotonic_clock`.

Comment: [12:09]camill_a@/home/camill_a[4]$ g++ -v
[...]
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Comment: Is g++4.7 a wide used version? Is this stable? I am currently installing it this way 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/168947/how-to-upgrade-g-to-4-7-1

Comment: And a last comment, what are the differences betwin monotonic and steady?

Comment: Ok finally I used monotonic instead of steady. Thanks a lot Jehan.

Comment: @Mayerz g++ 4.7.3 is currently the oldest maintained version. g++ 4.8.0 has already been released, and g++ 4.8.1 and 4.9.0 are in progress. I think you can safely say that g++ 4.7.3 is a stable release.

Comment: Yhea I sadly discovered this 10 minutes ago! 
But this is a school project, and it have to be runned on school distro, and they use version 4.6.2 or something like that...

So I will just be using monotonic, and my mates will have to downgrade their archlinux g++ down to the unmaintained version. This is funny.

Comment: @Mayerz Consider yourself lucky. My school still uses g++ 3.4 :)

Comment: @Mayerz - `monotonic_clock` was in early drafts of the `chrono` specification. It was replaced by `steady_clock`, which has more useful semantics.